# Получать данные с Ардуино на Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-8, bluetooth, arduino

У меня есть программа, которая находит peer и подключается к нему(arduino c hc-05 блютуз модулем).Я написал функцию, которая получает данные с этого блютуза.

```
private async void read()
{
    try
    {
        uint bytesRead = await dataReader.LoadAsync(sizeof(uint));
        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            uint strLenght = (uint)dataReader.ReadUInt32();
            bytesRead = await dataReader.LoadAsync(strLenght);
            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                String message = dataReader.ReadString(strLenght);
                messageTextBlock.Text = message.ToString();
                read();
            }
        }
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        messageTextBlock.Text = ex.Message;
    } }
```

Но она не работает.В чем может быть ошибка, либо может использовать другой метод?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так

```
private async void read() {
    try {
        uint bytesRead = await dataReader.LoadAsync(sizeof(uint));
        bytesRead.AsTask.Wait();
        uint count = bytesRead.GetResults();
        if (count == sizeof(int)) {
            uint strLenght = (uint)dataReader.ReadUInt32();
            bytesRead = await dataReader.LoadAsync(strLenght);
            bytesRead.AsTask.Wait();
            count = bytesRead.GetResults();
            if (count == 4) {
                String message = dataReader.ReadString(strLenght);
                messageTextBlock.Text = message.ToString();
                read();
                }}}
    catch (Exception ex) {
        messageTextBlock.Text = ex.Message;
        }}
```

Comment: ошибку выдаёт в bytesRead,AsTask.Wait();                  WindowsRuntimeSystemExtensions.AsTask(IAsyncAction)' is a method, which is not valid in the given context

Comment: ошибку исправил  IAsyncOperation<uint> bytesRead = dataReader.LoadAsync(sizeof(uint)); и bytesRead.AsTask().Wait();  Но выдаёт ошибку Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: @GerrDott ну значит экземпляр объекта не создан, значит `dataReader.LoadAsync(sizeof(uint));` дает `null` скорее всего. Что-то я не посмотрел что вопрос давно задан, хотя в списке один из первых :З